Timestamps of result elements of window function in Apache Flink
The Flink documentation says "The only relevant information that is set on the result elements is the element timestamp [...] which is [set to] end timestamp - 1 [...]"
In case I have to consecutive event time windows, where the first one is a tumbling window with a size of 5s and the second one is a sliding window with a size of 5s and a slide of of 1s, does this mean the second window will emit 5 times the same values within an aligned 5s event time period (assuming no late events)?

If you have a 5-minute sliding window consuming the output of a 5-minute tumbling window, then the sliding window will only see as input a burst of events coming every 5 minutes, when the tumbling window emits its results -- all of which will carry the same timestamp.

Is there a specific reason why the timestamp of events emitted by windows is set to the end of the window and not, for example, to the maximum timestamp of the events in the window?
